# Make IIS 7.5 pass *.xml requests to asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

How do I configure IIS 7.5 to forward all *.xml file requests to asp.net engines so i can handle them in Global.asax and rewrite the path to a *.aspx file? Now IIS is expecting to find them directly on disk. I will use this do dynamically generate my sitemap.xml

Comment: you should use custom http handler in order to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force static files to go through the ASP.NET pipeline by editing your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="XMLHandler" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*.xml" verb="GET"  />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

1. [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.ASPX)
2. [How to: Register HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.ASPX)

Comment: Thinking about it though, I don't know why you'd want to do it this way. Likely a better route to take for dynamic site map.