# Pull JSON file from .NET folder with AJAX / Fullcalender events JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, fullcalendar

I am trying to store a JSON file in a folder in my .NET project (`/Content/events/events.json`) and then pull it into an AJAX call, I keep trying to put this information in for the field `events:` for the add-on **[Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)**.

My attempt

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month'
    },
    defaultDate: 'new Date()',
    editable: true,
    events: {
        url: '/Content/events/events.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
       //other code stuff
    }
});
```

Each time I try a new attempt, I just receive a `GET 404 error`. Right now I am testing this via localhost debugging is VS, but this will be put online once I get it working.

How can I set a AJAX call to get this JSON file for the `events:` parameter?

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> `http://localhost:56087/Content/events/document.json?start=1404014400&end=1407643200&_=1406577499130`

**[Fullcalendar Site](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)**

I have already tried their github method, but I cannot seem to get that to work either, thus why I am trying to pull this information from a local/server file.

I can hardcode the `events` as such,

```
...
events: 
[
  {
    title: 'Bi-weekly Meeting',
    start: '2014-07-09',
    color: 'red'
  }
],
...
```

But this means I have to open the application source code to modify any event changes. What I want is to be able to modify this JSON file **outside of the application** so that me, or other users may modify the events.

Comment: Make a controller or aspx page that serves as your document.json and have the codebehind read the file and process the query parameters instead.

Comment: Is your .NET project MVC or WebForms?

Comment: @xDaevax it is MVC, I have a controller but right now it just shows the Index. I have tried implementing a reader to read in the JSON, but that isn't working either. :/

Comment: Make sure you add an ignore route mapping in your global.  If you're getting a 404, MVC's route handler is likely trying to hijack your request (since almost everything is extensionless in MVC).

Comment: Likely the static file isn't being served up by IIS. If you hit the `json` file directly, you should see the reason on *why* it isn't being served up. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19069783/1810243 as a solution (just use *.json instead of *.xml). But, if you want people to modify the JSON file, you should strongly consider using a database to store your events, and to make a controller to build and serve the content.

Comment: I am no longer getting an error, and if manually navigate to the JSON file I can see it in the browser(used to be blocked before). Any idea why fullcalendar is still not appearing correctly? The JSON looks right, and I have everything setup correctly in their documentation. Example JSON `[{title:"Bi-weekly Meeting",start:"2014-07-09",color:"red"},{title:"5 v 5 Inhouse",start:"2014-07-01",color:"purple"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the MVC RouteHandler is hijacking your request for the JSON file.  Try adding something like the following to your global.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("*.json");
```

Make sure to add it close to the top so MVC can weed it out quickly without going through your other routes.

Comment: Okay, so I am no longer getting an error, and if manually navigate to the JSON file I can see it in the browser(used to be blocked before). Any idea why fullcalendar is still not appearing correctly? The JSON looks right, and I have everything setup correctly in their documentation. Example JSON `[{title:"Bi-weekly Meeting",start:"2014-07-09",color:"red"},{title:"5 v 5 Inhouse",start:"2014-07-01",color:"purple"}]`

Comment: @Austin For valid JSON, the field names as well as the values should be strings.  Try running your JSON through the JSONLint validator here: http://jsonlint.com/  Your result should be something like: "[
    {
        "title": "Bi-weekly Meeting",
        "start": "2014-07-09",
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "title": "5 v 5 Inhouse",
        "start": "2014-07-01",
        "color": "purple"
    }
]"

Comment: Actually I got it working and I think it was simply some formatting issues. i.e. in the manual version I could say `"title":todays event` which is fine, but when I named it as `"title":"todays event"` it seems to work. I also smashed it all down into a single JSON line, as I think it was adding `/r/n` all over the place due to the formatting of the manual events. Not sure what did it, but it works. Thank you for suggesting the routes option though as that allowed me to access it in the first place! +1

Comment: Question regarding using routes.IgnoreRoute, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019607/did-my-routes-and-congif-changes-break-something-server-side-mvc-5